# How to handle resolutions for Windows Phone 8 HTML5 + JavaScript games?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, windows-phone-8

I am making my first mobile game using the HTML5 canvas tag as well as JavaScript. The only external library I currently use is jQuery.

When I loaded my game onto my phone (Lumia 920), which has a 1280 x 768 resolution, the canvas (with the same resolution) was twice as high and wide. I heard that phones generally don't use the max resolution, but rather half of it or similar, which would display this.

So how could you make sure that the game supports all (I think 4) available resolutions? Would you have the canvas be 100% wide and tall, does WP8 have some way of automatically resizing, and is it usually necessary to have different images for different resolutions to ensure high quality?

Answer (score 1):

CSS Pixels are differrent from device pixel.

The best example would be ipad and ipad retina.

A canvas of width 300px  in ipad would be of physically same size as in Ipad retina, even though ipad is of resolution 768 * 1024  but ipad Retina  is of 1536 * 2048.

This is because both the device are of same CSS PIXEL width .and Only thing which is changing is the density ratio which is 2 for retina device.

The same case is applicable to your LUMIA 920 Device to.
Also, If you want to determine CSS pixels size , then divide the screen resolution by density

1536/2 = 768